# 1/4" metal pin through a 2x4: unthreaded t-nut or metal sleeve to prevent fretting (wear from small movements)?

Tags: connectors

I want to secure fittings to a 2x4. These fittings will have holes that line up with holes in the 2x4. Thick metal pins will hold the fitting in place, but I want to reinforce the 2x4 so the pin will not enlarge the hole.

I think I'm looking for an unthreaded t-"nut", or perhaps a sleeve bushing.

Does this have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1):

Buy something like this: [https://www.amazon.com/Z-Threaded-Insert-Internal-Threads/dp/B002WC8TQ6](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B002WC8TQ6) screw it in, and drill out the interior threads.

[image: threaded brass insert]

Answer (score 0):

Not so much elegant but likely less expensive than inserts would be to find the right size steel tubing to fit your bolts and cut them to length for the hole, drilled to match the OD of the tubing. You would want the length of the tubing to be slightly smaller than the depth of the hole, and using washers, compress the wood until the bolt will not tighten more. If the washer you use has a larger ID than the OD of the tubing, you can compress until the nut hits the bushing, or stack more washers for more compression.

Answer (score 0):

Cheap bushing could just be a piece of steel or Al tube, cut to length and secured in the hole with epoxy or polyurethane glue.